# populate the table first row with the output of the mapped function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How shall i populate the table first row with the output of the mapped function in jQuery. Something like of below.

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find("td:first").map(function(x, i) {
            return i;
        }).html()
    });
```

Comment: what value you do want to insert in first td ?

Comment: series from 2 to .. to length of tds.

Comment: You mean first row td will be 2 and second row td will be 3 and so on ?

Comment: yes that's correct. first row td will get 2 and second row td will get 3 and so on.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/tzcxkyv7/  you mean ?

Comment: yes that worked thats what i looked thank you.

Comment: @Help post your comment as answer

Comment: Done @Madhavan.V :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `map` function is meant for arrays and the array with your code will be the element.

You should try `index()` of the row to get your desired result.

[Working sample](https://jsfiddle.net/tzcxkyv7/)

Glad to Help :)

-Help